# Laravel Collections: extract specified set of keys and set the non-existing keys to a default value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently using the `only` method to extract a certain set of keys from a `Collection`. This method extracts the specified keys from the `Collection` and doesn't extract a key if it does not exist. I am wondering if there is also a way to extract non-existing keys from a `Collection` and have a default value for the non-existing keys in the result.

This is the current behaviour of the `only` method:

```php
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false]);

$filtered = $collection->only(['product_id', 'name', 'quantity']);

$filtered->all();

// ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']
```

The behaviour I am looking for is:

```php
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false]);

$filtered = $collection->only(['product_id', 'name', 'quantity']);

$filtered->all();

// ['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'quantity'=>'']
```

Is there a way of doing this? Preferably using one of the `Collection`'s methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this.

```
// The main collection to filter from
$main = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false]);


// From the filters array, create an empty collection with the default values
$toFilter = collect([
  'product_id' => '', 
  'name' => '', 
  'quantity' => '',
]);

// Set the the values from the main collection, 
$filteredResult = $toFilter->map(function($item, $key) use($main){

    return $main[$key] ?? $item ;

});
```

You should get the final collection as expected

```
$filteredResult->all()
```

```
[
   "product_id" => 1,
   "name"       => "Desk",
   "quantity"   => "",
]
```